# XenServer increase vm-disk error

Tags: disk, xen

We have currently the XenServer Version 6.2 with SP1 and the updates to XS62ESP1014.

If we tried to increase one of our vm disks, then there is an error:

```
[root@xenserver-xx ~]# xe vdi-resize uuid=5101f789-78c2-44e1-9a06-7fe7794dd98e disk-size=100GiB
Error code: SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_110
Error parameters: , VDI resize failed [opterr=Command ['/usr/sbin/lvcreate', '-n', 'inflate_5101f789-78c2-44e1-9a06-7fe7794dd98e_53800337408', '-L', '4', 'VG_XenStorage-81d9f03d-b7fc-80f3-240e-9f6a172059c7', '--addtag', 'journaler', '--inactive', '--zero=n'] failed (3): /usr/sbin/lvcreate: unrecognized option `--inactive'
  Error during parsing of command line.],
```

The lvcreate version:

```
[root@xenserver-xx ~]# lvcreate --version
  LVM version:     2.02.88(2)-RHEL5 (2014-04-04)
  Library version: 1.02.67-RHEL5 (2011-10-14)
  Driver version:  4.15.0
```

The redhat version:

```
[root@xenserver-xx ~]# more /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
```

Does sombody know somthing about this error or have somebody the some problem?
Is there a way to fix this?

The problem is also there, then we create a new vm disc and try the increase the disc immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution:

The Probelm was that XenServer needs a special version of lvm.

```
LVM version:     2.02.88(2)-RHEL5 (2014-04-04)
Library version: 1.02.67-RHEL5 (2011-10-14)
Driver version:  4.15.0
```

In this case lvcreate is a symbolic lik to lvm and the newer version has other arguments to increase one of the vm disks.

My workaround is that I copied the old version from an other XenServer to this XenServer and exchange the lvcreate link.

```
copy lvm__2_02_84_2 into /usr/sbin/
cp /usr/sbin/
chmod 555 lvm__2_02_84_2
ls -lah lv*    # check if lvm and lvm__2_02_84_2 are not different (rights)
mv lvcreate lvcreate_<date>_bak     # <date> e.g. 2014-12-02  # backup the old link
ln -s lvm__2_02_84_2 lvcreate       # create the new link
ls -lah lv*    # check again
```

Perhaps it's better to exchange the hole lvm:

```
copy lvm__2_02_84_2 into /usr/sbin/
cp /usr/sbin/
chmod 555 lvm__2_02_84_2
ls -lah lv*    # check if lvm and lvm__2_02_84_2 are not different (rights)
mv lvm lvm_<date>_bak     # <date> e.g. 2014-12-02  # backup the old link
mv lvm__2_02_84_2 lvm     # create the new link
ls -lah lv*    # check again
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing some hotfixes. 
You can try to run rpm -qa| grep lvm2 
If your RPM name doesn't have 'xs' string, then definately there is some lvm2 related update is missing.

e.g.

[root@xenserver~]# rpm -qa | grep lvm
lvm2-2.02.88-12.xs1420